# How do I get client's port number from the server?

Tags: sockets, client-server, port

I have written a simple client-server program. I am able to print the port number of client in the client program. The values are dynamic.

But when I try to print it in the server program, it gives me the port number of the server and not the client.

```
connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*) &cliaddr, &clilen);

cout<<"Server: Server's Port: "<< ntohs(servaddr.sin_port)<<endl; /*23112*/
cout<<"Server: Client's Port: "<< ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port)<<endl; /*23112*/
```

I am using the same in client program, and it is printing the random ports correctly.
I have initialized them this way:

```
struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, servaddr;
socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
```

Comment: Please show how you are initializing `clilen` before the call to `accept`. And show how `servaddr`, `cliaddr`, and `clilen` are declared too, for good measure.

Comment: You didn't show the initialization of `clilen`, only its declaration.

Comment: @Celada `clilent = sizeof(clilen);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize 'clilen':

> The addrlen argument is a value-result argument: the caller must
>   initialize it to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed
>   to by addr; on return it will contain the actual size of the peer
>   address.

Comment: I've initialized like this:
`clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);`